# view souce vs firebug inspect element

Tags: java, firefox, firebug, httpclient

I have a scenario where I use Httpclient to get the HTML repsonse of a page which is same as ViewSouce that we right click and get. There are certains tags which has

```
<img alt="abc"  /> and other tags

<img alt="def" src="/images/xyz.jpg" />
```

These are the tags I see through View Source.

However when i use the firebug inspect element I see a valid url for each image.
for example above

```
<img alt="abc"  />
```

looks like

```
<img alt="abc" src="/images/fgh.jpg" />
```

What is happening? I assume that view source gets the code before the images a re loaded so the urls are missing. I know im wrong...but i dont know a reason for this. Can someone help me. I want to get the urls for all the images as i see throught the firebug inspect element. Thanks.

Comment: are you using any Content Delivery Network to fetch the images? if that is the case, then view source will not give the exact path of the image. In that case, it will give you the path on the CDN server and will be rendered by the browser while displaying.

Comment: sounds like there's javascript involved that modifies the source. Could you point us to the site in question? Might help to get a look.

Comment: Take a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789069/viewing-actual-source-code-of-a-website

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View source shows the HTML provided by the webserver, and Firebug inspector show the "source" after being rendered by the browser: that means that if something has changed in the client (for example using javascript) you can see the changes through the Firebug inspector, but not through the "view-source" option.

Comment: Thanks. I think there is a Javascript that changes. In that case what is the work around?

Comment: I think there should be something in Firebug that allows you to "break" (as in debug) your javascript files whenever an attribute (your "src" attribute) changes.  I'll admit I've never used that feature, though.

Answer (score 1):

xavivars is right, but I just felt there was a better way to put it.

1. View Source is the response *as seen by the client* from the server for the current page.
   (In some browsers, like Chrome, I've seen the "view-source:" actually reload content from the server, btw).
2. Firebug Inspector shows the current Document Object Model (DOM) of your page.  Javascript can change things around on your page, adding or removing elements, or what not (Same goes with plugins or GreaseMonkey).